# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="guided-tour-tag-credentials-new"]"}

Tags: python, selenium

I want to use selenium to create credentials here , but it shows error :

**what "iframe xpath here" should I replace here?**
here is my code content:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe xpath here")))

driver.get("https://ms.web.purview.azure.com/resource/prod0719/main/catalog/management/accountInformation?feature.tenant=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47")

driver.set_window_size(1200, 900)
sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_id("managementCredentials").click()
sleep(5)
```

Message:

> ```
> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="guided-tour-tag-credentials-new"]"}
>   (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=91.0.864.70)
> ```

here is my code content now after switching to iframe:
[image]

iframe content:

screenshot2:
[image]

screenshot3:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an iframe, if it is, you need to switch first before interaction  :

**Code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe xpath here")))
```

and then you can interact :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("guided-tour-tag-credentials-new").click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

once done, switch to default content like this  :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Possibly you have to add wait before accessing that element to let him loaded.
2. Possibly it is inside an iframe.
3. Possibly the id attribute is dynamically changing on the page

Comment: tried above solution , but it failed as screenshot2 now

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: attached screenshot3 ,you can check the definition for new button element

Comment: any suggestions about above issue?

Comment: Picture is not enough. We need a link to the website.

Comment: granted you permission to below this link https://ms.web.purview.azure.com/resource/prod0719/main/datasource/management/credentials?feature.tenant=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47

Comment: I can't enter there

Comment: is this your alias ?  v-joprop@microsoft.com right ?

Comment: try this prod0721 account , you need to refresh this page many times if you cannot access it    https://ms.web.purview.azure.com/resource/prod0721/main/datasource/management/credentials?feature.tenant=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47

Comment: check the element is under an iframe , i use xpath to switch to it ,but it shows time out

Comment: what is the password?

Comment: where and what password you need? open above link?

Comment: added iframe element content as below

Comment: <iframe class="css-12bxjji-ExtensionIFrame-ExtensionUIContainer" src="https://datasource.ms.ext.web.purview.azure.com/1.20210719.721?extensionName=datasource&amp;entry=ui&amp;shellOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fms.web.purview.azure.com&amp;code=6c8cdfce-47ca-4d42-8f28-e21de55d7f48" id="f5e687bf-f22b-41ef-916b-a75706171f57" role="presentation" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-downloads" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Comment: can you check if `/iframe[@role="presentation"]` is unique locator on the entire page?

Comment: attached screenshot 2, checked all role under iframe is presentation

Comment: I see. Try this locator: `//iframe[contains(@src,'sensitivity.ms')]`.

Comment: thanks for your update , it still cannot find element , error messages as screenshot3